# Error on loading "0 A.D" saved game

Tags: games, 0ad

I use `Ubuntu 14.04` and installed `0 A.D alpha XV:osiris`. I can save and load `skirmish` and `scenario` map types. But I got this error on loading `random` map type:

```
Failed to load saved game state. It might have been saved with an incompatible version of game.
```

Although I saved game with same version of `0 A.D`. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: You might get better help through "0 A.D."-specific channels, such as the ones listed at https://play0ad.com/community/support/

Comment: @NickWeinberg Thank you! I will try that . But I saw some question about that game in this site. So asked this question here.

Comment: Yup! Please don't take my comment as criticism; it's just that your question seems to be very narrowly about that game in particular, and I think you might have better luck on a forum dedicated to the game. Good luck, wherever you receive help!